# Antlr4 semantic predicate to match user-defined delimiters

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I have a parser which accepts two different types of predefined HTML-template tags.  One is explicitly terminated with an "end*", and one is not e.g.:

```
{% for ... %}
   An explicitly-terminated tag
{% endfor %}

{% assign x = 'my implicitly-terminated tag' %}
```

That works fine, but I also need to allow a user to define his own tags from C# code, so I need Antlr4 to match these examples:

```
{% mycustomtag %}
   ...
{% endmycustomtag %}

{% myunterminatedtag %}
```

I tried to match anything that starts with `{% [USERDEFINED] %}` with an ending tag `{% end[USERDEFINED] %}` by using a C# semantic predicate, as follows:

```
tag: // ...
    | custom_blocktag 
    | custom_tag
    // ...

// an explicitly-terminated tag
custom_blocktag:    TAGSTART custom_block_start_tag customtagblock_expr* TAGEND custom_blocktag_block TAGSTART custom_block_end_tag TAGEND { _localctx.custom_block_end_tag().GetText().Equals("end" + _localctx.custom_block_start_tag().GetText()) }?;

// an implicitly-terminated tag
custom_tag:         TAGSTART tagname customtag_expr* TAGEND ;
```

Unfortunately, this works correctly only if I have no implicitly-terminated tags occurring before explicitly terminated tags, but it fails if it occurs in the opposite order.

This fails with an error:

`{% xyz \"Test\" %}{% abc \"hello\"%}...{% endabc %}`

However, this works fine:

`{% abc \"hello\"%}...{% endabc %}{% xyz \"Test\" %}`

As I understand it, if I want the semantic predicate to prevent the match from succeeding (rather than matching the rule and THEN failing and generating an error) I would need the semantic predicate on the left.  However, the semantic predicate won't have any values if it is on the left---so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Is there a way to write the parser rules so that I can define both these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have described the problem, the only syntactic certainty that can be determined from any one tag is that the end tag of a paired set has a name that starts with 'end'.  That a begin tag will occur before an end tag is really a semantic association (the 'for' -> 'endfor' relation can be used to confirm the association, but does not really help syntactically).

The best general approach is to handle syntactic matters in the parser and semantic matters in parse-tree walkers.  Here, an initial walk to examine each tag and build a table of begin and end tags associations is easy.

Thus, just recognize tags in the parser without trying to qualify as begin, end or singleton.

```
tag: TBEG 
     ( id expression  // assign etc
     | expression     // for etc
     | id             // endfor etc
     )
     TEND  // { processTag($tag); } // alternate solution
   ;
```

You can, in effect, achieve the same result purely in the parser by adding an action to the tag rule.  This action would create and add tags as encountered to tag table.  When an end-named tag is added, the prior tag would be marked as a begin tag.

If you are going to be implementing other walkers, as likely needed to implement the tag expressions, adding one more to pre-qualify the tags would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks!  Based on your answer I ended up pushing the begin/end semantics out of the parser, and then using a stack in the walker to reach back and mark matching "singleton" tags as "begin" tags.  Then it was a simple matter of reparenting the "begin" tag's sibling expressions between the begin- and end-tags so that they become children in the resulting AST.